# Ahoy events queries in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ahoy

I started code rails recently and I need to figure out this problem.

```
%td
  =  Ahoy::Event.where(name: "viewed_brochure").where_properties(brochure_id: brochure.id).select(:session_id).uniq
```

This should find number of distinct values of session_id in properties field but it doesn't work.

This line returns these and similar errors

```
#<Ahoy::Event::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f52d9325130>
#<Ahoy::Event::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f52d9466508>
```

---

```
%td
  =  Ahoy::Event.select { |event| event.properties['session_id'] }.uniq.count
```

I tried this line but this time returns number of rows in table

Comment: how `event` and `properties` are associated?

Comment: I use ahoy gem. So i have ahoy_events table and this table contains properties field. Generally ahoy queries use where_properties function find data. Btw properties field contains session_id.

Comment: what errors are you facing?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: What is the data type of properties attribute? Hstore or jsonb?

Comment: data type of properties is jsonb @Anton

Comment: I don't currently have a model with jsonb to test on.. can you try: Ahoy::Event.group("properties -> 'session_id'").count OR @> instead of ->

Comment: this is so close to figure out the problem your solution is return like these  
{"98d2c824477ee292507d7a28bce8a4a0"=>1, "ebbe52f15133dc3ce1b55a9acfdad98c"=>2}                                                                                                  I need to convert to number. This case must return 2.

Comment: @Emre, I'll make it an answer. Can you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to group by jsonb key, in your case properties['session_id']

```
Ahoy::Event.group("properties -> 'session_id'").count
```

This will return the counts on which you can apply .size or you could do distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u so much @Anton I modify your solution and finally it works fine.

Here is the solution

```
%td
  =  Ahoy::Event.where_properties(brochure_id: brochure.id).group("properties -> 'session_id'").count.size
```